# xargs ignoring 2nd script parameter

Tags: xargs, parameter

I'm calling a bash script with two parameters, let's call them `param_one` and `param_two`. I also have a file called `test` which contains two lines:

```
line_one
line_two
```

Here's what my script looks like:

```
cat test | xargs -I% bash -c 'echo % $1 $2;'
```

The output I am looking for is

```
line_one param_one param_two
line_two param_one param_two
```

but I keep getting this:

```
line_one
line_two
```

`xargs` is ignoring when I have more than one parameter in the script. Even if I change the script to this it just prints `param_oneparam_one`

```
cat test | xargs -I% bash -c 'printf '$1 $2';'
```

However, I need to use all three parameters - `%` from `xargs`, as well as `$1` and `$2` from when the script is called in the same `xargs` command. Any suggestions on the appropriate way to do this, or is `xargs` not a good fit for this?

Comment: are there any "funny" thing in arg  or line ? (space, new line ...)

Comment: @Archemar No, they're just normal strings of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
cat test | xargs -I% bash -c 'echo % $1 $2;'
```

`$1` and `$2` are passed as literal strings in the argument to `bash -c`, that is the inline-script. And `%` will also be expanded in that script, so treated as shell code. So, for instance if `test` contains `;reboot;`, that would make it call the `reboot` command.

You're not passing arguments to that inline script, so `$1`, `$2` will be empty.

You could do:

```
< test xargs -I% bash -c 'echo "$1" "$2" "$3"' bash % "$1" "$2"
```

To forward the argument of your script to your inline script, but if `$1` or `$2` also happen to contain `%` characters, they would be expanded by `xargs` as well in there.

So you could use the environment instead to pass those values:

```
< test PARAM1=$1 PARAM2=$2 xargs -I% bash -c '
  echo "$1" "$PARAM1" "$PARAM2"' bash %
```

Also note that `xargs` does some quote processing on the input, if you wanted the raw content of each line to be passed verbatim, that's not what you would use. With GNU `xargs`, you could do:

```
< test xargs -d '\n' -n 1 bash -c 'echo "$3" "$1" "$2"' bash "$1" "$2"
```

Also, don't forget to quote your variables. `printf` is more reliable than `echo`, but remember the first argument is the *format*, so shouldn't be *variable*.